# Sample collection is failing for dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

Google Cloud dataprep is showing summary of only sampled data at the top. This is not the analysis of all distinct data.

Now when I try to collect sample of data based on unique values in column then underlying dataflow job is failing.

Error that it gives is - for custom mode network, I need to specify subnetwork where job will run. However there is no control given to modify where sampling job will run?

Is there workaround or way so that I see full data instead of sample?

Answer (score 0):

Change the VPC under the user profile
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got an answer from you and now default network setting is changed at user profile level